# Serializing properties in sequence

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, xsd

I have a very complex XSD schema that I have converted to classes using the xsd.exe tool.  I had to add/edit a few settings to account for cases where elements contained the 'Choice' tag and the available choices were all of different custom types.  That all worked fine.

The problem I have just run into is that elements that contain the 'Sequence' tag do not always serialize in order.  I have tried forcing the order using the order attribute, for example:

```
<XmlElement(Order:=5)>
Public Property no_autor() As String
    Get
        Return Me.no_autorField
    End Get
    Set
        Me.no_autorField = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

However, the type that is not serializing properly is derived from a base type.  The base type only has two elements so I order them Order=1 and Order=2.  At this point it starts getting confusing.  The derived type is in a different class so do I start the ordering there at 1 or 3?  I have read some MSDN documentation that states that base types will always serialize first so I thought maybe derived types, even if ordering started at 1, would order correctly after the base types.  When I try starting at 1 or 3 I just get an unhelpful error briefly stating that the entire class could not serialize.

Also, if a property is decorated with

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()
```

do I still include it in the ordering?

Finally, is there a better way to enforce Sequence as it appears in the XSD file?  As I mentioned, this file is very complex and is full of Choice, Sequence and Extension tags.  Having to go through every element, adding Order ( and then have it fail over and over ) and accounting for all of the derived types (usually two or three deep) is not a very efficient use of time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to enforce ordering for elements within the Sequence tag.  When generating the class structure using xsd.exe, use the 'order' switch.  The resulting class file will contain all of the required Order attributes.

eg.

```
C:\folder>xsd mySchema.xsd /l:VB /c /order
```

Just as an aside, I don't see why the xsd utility wouldn't enforce ordering as it is described in the xsd file by default.  The Sequence tag is specifically meant to enforce a particular order in the contained elements.  Seems redundant to have to indicate that you want ordered elements to appear in order.